# XSLT - How to copy an xml element without one of his grandchildren?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml from which I am trying to copy all the contents of < a >, without the < ToRemove > elements and the text inside.

```
    <a>
      <b>
      ...
      </b>
      <c>
        <d>
          <e>
            <ToRemove someAttributes> value </ToRemove>
          </e>
          <f>
            <ToRemove someAttributes> value </ToRemove>
            <m/>
          </f>
        ...
        </d>
      </c>
    </a> 
    <z/>
    <w/>
```

I have an already existing xlst which I am trying to adapt, but none of the methods I have tried have removed it from the result.

````
    <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
      </xsl:template>
      
      <xsl:template match="a">
        <someTag1>
            <someTag2>
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </someTag2>
        </someTag1>
      </xsl:template>
    
      <xsl:template match="ToRemove"/> ```

The result should be:
````

```
<someTag1>
    <someTag2>
        <a>
          <b>
          ...
          </b>
          <c>
            <d>
              <e/>
              <f>
                <m/>
              </f>
            ...
            </d>
          </c>
        </a> 
    </someTag2>
</someTag1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example:

XML Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <parent>
     <child>
       <grandchild/>
     </child>
  </parent>
</root>
```

The Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
        <someTag1>
            <someTag2>
                <xsl:copy>
                   <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:copy>
            </someTag2>
        </someTag1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="grandchild" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <parent>
     <someTag1>
       <someTag2>
          <child>
       
          </child>
       </someTag2>
     </someTag1>
  </parent>
</root>
```

If you want to make `someTag1` as the root of your output document, add a `template` that will just do `apply-templates` without a copy like this:

```
<xsl:template match="grandparent | parent">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Use <xsl:copy-of select="@*" /> to copy attributes. 

<xsl:template match="child">
        <someTag1>
            <someTag2>
                <xsl:copy>
                   <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
                   <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:copy>
            </someTag2>
        </someTag1>
</xsl:template>